# Select data within the area of a series in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, scatter-plot

Ok, so I have two data series graphed, like so.

[image]

These are two scatter plots, based on x and y values, that are produced using a combo chart. The orange scatter plot is an ellipse whose calculation is based upon aspects relating to the purple scatter plot. I have made the orange ellipse in order to... well... select the part of the purple scatter plot that I want to do other things with. Problem is, I don't know how to *actually* select the  data points this area refers to.

The data for this chart is based upon four columns: A,B (forming the purple plot) and C,D (forming the orange plot). Reordering the columns makes little difference.

Implementing Anger's proposed solution below, all instances seem to return true. Also, there happen to be more scatter plot rows than there are ellipse rows, so I'm not sure how to solve that for the sake of comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify the equation of the ellipse (center point and semi-major/minor axes), you can use the equation of the [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) to flag points that are inside or outside.

if( ((Ex-x)/Lx)^2+((Ey-y)/Ly)^2 < 1, "INSIDE", "OUTSIDE")

Where Ex, Ey are the coordinates of the ellipse's center; x, y are your data point's coordinates, and Lx, Ly are the semi-major and semi-minor axes.

Just by eye, I would say Ex = 1.8, Ey = 1.21, Lx = 0.6, and Ly = 0.5.

Comment: Hi, I have a quick implementation query. If you wouldn't mind looking at my updated question above I'd appreciate it .

Comment: It looks like you're switching the axes and the data coordinates. Lx and Ly are constants for your given ellipse, like the center point. The only variables should be Scatterplot_X as x and Scatterplot_Y as y.